# XML Serialization Customized Partially

Tags: c#, xml

in brief what I need is that to custom the class project partially

```
public class project : IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string name;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string[] contents;
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

  public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
  {
      if (reader.HasAttributes)
      {
          contents=new string[reader.AttributeCount];
          for (int i = 0; i < reader.AttributeCount; i++)
          {
              reader.MoveToAttribute(i);
              string attr = reader.Name;
              Regex reg = new Regex(@"content_\d+");
              if (reg.IsMatch(attr))
              {
                  contents[i] = reader.Value;
              }
          }
      }
  }

  public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < contents.Count(); i++)
      {
          writer.WriteAttributeString("content_" + i, contents[i]);
      }
  }
}
```

I want name to be serialized normally but custom only the contents of the array (I need to make it as attribute in project node ).
what happen actually is when I implement the project class the name is kept null any idea how can I do this?

Comment: I *strongly* advise against implementing `IXmlSerializable` - I've seen *so many people* make a complete mess of that... it is not consumer-friendly.

Comment: it is a good way to go through if you want serialize a big recursive class but in custom way

Comment: I would say that if you have that scenario, you probably shouldn't be using `XmlSerilaizer` (or even xml) *in the first place*

Answer (score 0):

In `ReadXml` method you never assign `name` property. Just add

```
name= "someValue";
```

Comment: yes this truck is what I need to do with serialize not using code in the real example I have there is a doze of attribute I don't what you have done with code

Comment: @Miral I don't understand where is your problem, can you explain me  in a better way which is your goal?

Comment: I need to use serialization without implementation of public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader){} for apart of class and other part ( public string[] contents; to be customized) did you get it